# iOS hardcode user location

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, hardcode, userlocation

I would like to introduce a specific user location by code.
I only need to hardcode the userlocation to make an screenshot for the appStore.

Could somebody help me?

Thankyou!

Comment: Sounds like an tax writeoff business trip to me!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a GPX file with a single coordinate and add it to your project.  Once created, you can then select the "location services" arrow in xcode, then select the GPX file you created with your one coordinate in it.

- File>New..File>iOS-Resource>GPX File
- Then replace the default coords in there with your desired location coords.
- Run your app
- Select the "location services" arrow and select the name of the GPX file you created.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Core Location, override it and plug in your own Coordinates.

Just make sure you revert back before you ship :p

Comment: if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;  // what i write here?